# Returning the next node

Tags: c, linked-list, comparative-review, pointers, null

What is considered to be a good programming practice for returning value from the function? For example, if we have a function in `C` named `list* after( list *node)`, which returns the node which is after the `node` pointer.

First option:

```
node *after(node *first_ptr, node *nod_ptr)
{

    if (!(is_last(first_ptr, nod_ptr)) && !( first_ptr==NULL) && nod_ptr != NULL ) {

        while (first_ptr != nod_ptr && first_ptr != NULL){

            first_ptr = first_ptr->next;

        }

        return first_ptr != NULL ? first_ptr->next : NULL;

    }

     return NULL;

}
```

Second option:

```
node *after(node *first_ptr, node *nod_ptr)
{

    node *temp=NULL;
    if (!(is_last(first_ptr, nod_ptr)) && !( first_ptr==NULL) && nod_ptr != NULL ) {

        while (first_ptr != nod_ptr){

            first_ptr = first_ptr->next;
            temp = first_ptr;
            if(temp == NULL){

              break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }


    }

     return temp;

}
```

Here `node` is `typedef` structure and `next` is a pointer to next element in the list and `is_last(node *,node *)` checks whether the second argument pointer is the last element in the list having start pointer as the first argument.

I'm wondering, in general, if big functions are necessary. Which seems nicer to understand?

Comment: It seems the function should just return `node_ptr->next`. Why you need the loop in the function?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko loop is there to check whether the nod_ptr is in list pointed by first_ptr.

Comment: I think, it's clearer to have the function `is_node_in_list` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `after()` function is actually doing two things: it returns `nod_ptr->next`, but with the stipulation that the list starting at `first_ptr` contains `nod_ptr`.  Therefore, you should decompose it into two functions.

```
/**
 * Returns the content node if it is contained in the list starting at
 * head, otherwise NULL.  The list must not contain a cycle.
 */
node *find(node *head, node *content)
{
    for (node *n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next)
    {
        if (n == content)
        {
            return content;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/**
 * If the list starting at head contains content, returns content->next.
 * Otherwise, returns NULL.
 */
node *after(node *head, node *content)
{
    return (content != NULL && find(head, content)) ? content->next
                                                    : NULL;
}
```